# How can I send data without POSTFIELDS in PHP curl?

Tags: php, rest

I'm using a REST API through PHP and I'm a bit confused on the CURL_POSTFIELDS behavior, which implies that I must send a querystring or array, but what I'm seeking to do is just to send a string of JSON text.

In the API I'm using there is no such thing as a field: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Edit+issues

So, how can I just send data that doesn't get interpreted as a query string, and without having to use a file?

Comment: Try: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);`

Comment: Actually, I'm using CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST with $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to handle custom methods, the method is not the problem

Comment: If you don't set CURLOPT_POST to true, you aren't sending a regular (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) POST request. Try it out and see what happens. Reading your question a second time, I think I'm completely missing its point. Care to be a bit more specific on exactly what you are trying to do and why you even looked at CURL_POSTFIELDS? All the API's examples are PUT requests, not POST ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                    
);
```

That way the content sent in the POSTFIELDS gets interpreted the right way. Source: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Answer (score 0):

I found an article about using [JSON with PHP/CURL](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)

In general, we do pretty much this but with an XML-RPC request:

```
curl_setopt($cnxn, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cnxn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cnxn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
```

We just build the XML document for the RPC request into the `$body` variable, and our server will read it as the request body. We use Zend Framework MVC, but you can read the incoming raw request body from the `php://input` stream if you're rolling your own.